# how to Make a button disabled for 10 minutes even after refresh?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable button for 10 minutes after clicking on it and even on refresh it will remain disabled. How can i make it in javascript or jquery ? I just cant seem to make it for my code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
       $(document).ready(function(){
   var limit = 10*60*1000; 
                   btn.attr("disabled", true);
                btn.css('cursor','not-allowed');
                message.text('wrong answer, please wait 10 minutes before trying again');
   var timer = setTimeout(disableMyButton, limit);

   function disableMyButton(){
              btn.removeAttr("disabled");
                    message.text('');
      localStorage.setItem("isMyButtonDisabled", "true");
   }

   if(localStorage.getItem("isMyButtonDisabled") == "true"){
               message.text('');
               btn.removeAttr("disabled");

     window.clearTimeout(timer);
   }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: In a tamper-proof way? Very hard if you do it client-side.

Comment: You need to use database if you want to be 100% it won't be clicked. If you just don't want it to appear and you have back-end validation, just use HTML5 Storage or cookies.

Comment: In a non-tamper-proof way, I would change the approach. Save the current timestamp to the local storage when the button is pressed, then check every now and then to see if the current timestamp minus the saved timestamp is more than 10 minutes. In that case, re-enable the button.

Comment: @DawidZbiński a database is not really needed, per se. Did you mean server-side code instead?

Comment: Instead of just adding and removing the `disabled` attribute, add and remove the click event handler as well. Otherwise there's nothing stopping me from inspecting the button, removing the `disabled` attribute myself and clicking the button before the 10 minutes it up.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea.  Use the localStorage but put the timestamp in there.  Then when the page is loaded, grab the timestamp from localStorage.  If the difference between the localStorage timestamp and now is over 10 minutes, then enable the button.  If not, set the timeout appropiately.  The only problem is keeping the localStorage clean.  Make sure you wipe out the timestamp at the end of the 10 minutes.

Comment: can you clarify by writing code please?... because i tried what you told me but it is not working unfortunately

Comment: Something like this:<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
  var now = getDate();
  //Check if the time exists
  var then = localStorage.getItem("timestamp");
  //if it doesn't exist, put in it
  if(then typeof 'undefined'){
   localStorage.setItem("timestamp", now);
   then=now;
  }
  
     //Then take the difference in time between now and the then  
     if((now-then > 600s){
   enable button
  }
  else{
   setTimeout(enableButton(), now-then);
  }
 });

 function enableButton(){
  enable the button
 }
 </script>